# Remove extension with RewriteRule

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm having some problems removing the extension of the following rewrite rule..

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /index.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

How can I get rid of the extension and use it like `domain.com/23` instead of `domain.com/23.html`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ /index.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```